# How to show progress dialog on home activity android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I have a bottom navigation view, and this view has 3 items 3 different fragments.

In my one fragment I am uploading a video file to server.

**My question is :**

When upload start I want to show uploading progress from my main activity like instagram doing.

How can do this ? any advice please

Comment: add the code and we can show where to add

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
pd.setMessage("Your Message");
pd.show(); //Where you want to show PD
pd.dismiss();// where you want to Dismiss PD
```